# How to use energy conservation in following case

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, capacitance

A capacitor of capacitance C is intially uncharged is connected with a battery of emf ε.Find the heat dissipated in the circuit during charging?How can we apply energy conservation  although there are no two diffrent instances of time . the formula of energy conservation where i had doubt is

HEAT GENRATED(LOSS OF ENERGY)=ENERGY SUPPLIED BY BATTERIES - ENERGY CONSUMED BY BATTERIES + ENERY STORED IN CAPACITOR INTIALLY - ENERGY STORED IN CAPACITOR FINALLY

Comment: The heat generated is equal to the difference between the work done by batteries and the final potential energy of the system of capacitors. Well you can apply first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: You have repeated your question twice:-https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/481799/question-on-capacitor

Comment: Please do not ask new questions that are identical to previous ones. If you would like to clarify [your original question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/481799/question-on-capacitor), use the 'edit' button under the tags to update the question. Doing so will automatically put it in the Reopen queue for users to check if it has improved.